# How to handle null keys in JSON response?

Tags: apex, callout, null-pointer, httpresponse

I have a json response class like this:

```
public with sharing class Response {
    public Person person;
    
    public class Person {
        public PersonData personData = new PersonData ();
        public Death death = new Death();
    }
    .....
    public class Death {
        public String yearOfDeath;
        public String dayOfDeath;
        public String monthOfDeath;
    }
    ....
}
```

I can get a response such as:

```
{
   "Person": {
             PersonData: {
                          "Name":"x"
                          "Surname":"x",
                          "DateOfBirth":"12-12-1980",
             }
}
```

Note that there is no `Death` in the response. The callout class captures the response, `Response personResp = JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), Response.class))` and sends `personResp` to the lwc controller class, where I have an `AccountWrapper` class, which has variables for which the values of `personResp` will be assigned like this:

```
AccountWrapper accountWrapper = new AccountWrapper();
accountWrapper.personDeathYear = person.death.yearOfDeath;
```

This wrapper class is sent to front end for displaying the fields. The problem is if I do:

```
accountWrapper.personDeathYear = person.death.yearOfDeath;
```

I get `Attempt to de-reference a null object`. Now, I can put `null` check at 2nd level i.e., for death, but I have others that go like this:

```
accountWrapper.streetName = person.addressData.address.addressEnglish.streetName; //5 levels
```

Is there a better way than putting null check at every level for each accountWrapper variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Safe Navigation Operator](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm) (`?.`) to safely ignore null values:

```
accountWrapper.personDeathYear = person.death?.yearOfDeath;
```

This returns null the moment a NullPointerException would instead be thrown. This is far easier than adding getters or explicitly checking null values via ternary operators.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do it. Here I would probably just add a getter on `Person`.

```
public class Person
{
    public Death death;
    public Integer yearOfDeath
    {
        get
        {
            return death == null ? null : death.yearOfDeath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so its basically like adding if statements at every level, but using getter methods, right?

Comment: Yeah. And you can one line it. You have to put the if statements somewhere. But you haven't really shown us a clear picture of how you're consuming this data, so it's hard to say what would be the cleanest approach.

Comment: I am doing JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), Person.class), if you meant by consume.

Comment: also why are you putting yearOfDeath under Person class? it is a variable under Death class

Comment: That's only the first step in consumption.

Comment: I made some modifications to the post. Let me know if its more clear. I am not modifying the response data, just displaying it.

Comment: P.S. New Safe Navigation Operator: `return death?.yearOfDeath;`